# Will two defer calls for the same function be both executed?

Tags: go, defer-keyword

What happens to the `defer` in the code below?

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("http://google.com")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    resp, _ = http.Get("http://stackoverflow.com")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

There are two HTTP `GET` calls, both return to the same variable. Does `defer` stack the operation, leading to two `Close()` calls, or will only one be executed when `main()` finishes? (if the latter: will that be the first or second `defer` that gets executed?)

Comment: The answer, as often, lies in the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements): "_Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew_ [...]". In your example, two deferred calls will be executed; the value at the point of each deferred statement will be used.

Comment: The tricky part here is whether `resp` and then `resp.Body` is a `struct` that gets *overwritten* by the second `http.Get`, or whether it's a *pointer* and the second `http.Get` gets a new and different `resp` and `resp.Body`. Since `http.Get` returns a new pointer each time, this does the right thing. See the linked duplicate for more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `defer` does stack the reference to the variable `resp` leading to two `Close` calls. For example, in the following code, the `cleanUp` function is called with two different `A` Values:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Resp struct {
    A int
}

func (r *Resp) cleanUp() {
    fmt.Println("Cleaned up ", r.A)
}

func main() {
    r := &Resp{1}   
    defer r.cleanUp()   
    
    fmt.Println("I am doing something here!")

    r = &Resp{2}
    defer r.cleanUp()
}
```

Above code outputs:

```
I am doing something here!
Cleaned up  2
Cleaned up  1
```

Thus even though the value of `r` is overwritten, it doesn't lead to overwriting of variable in the `defer` statement.

Comment: I have no doubts that two **different** `defer`  statements will both be executed. My problem is that both use the same `resp` (with different values) so if, say, a pointer was used then only one would have been executed.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a pointer or not. If defer is used twice then the corresponding method/s will get executed twice.

Comment: I have updated the above answer.

Comment: @SaiRaviTejaK While it doesn’t matter to be executed twice, in this particular case it matter for correctness, it will close 2 time the second resp at the end. See: [on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JFfyRZBGItz)

Comment: @WoJ For correctness, you need to use 2 different resp variables. See [on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JFfyRZBGItz) if you use the same.

Comment: @mgagnon: thanks - so as I was suspecting, both calls (and now it does not matter that they are two of them) will handle only one (the last) call. This is what I was concerned with. Could you please turn your comment into an answer because it will be the correct one (= deferring twice will in fact only make one actual close)

Comment: @mgagnon Then this is not at all related to the `defer` statement. You are invoking same method (on same instance) twice. And since `defer` executes only at the end of the function execution both `defer` statements will be invoking same `method`

Comment: @SaiRaviTejaK Ho, I think you are right: May be this example would describe better the OP's case: https://play.golang.org/p/YV3W23ZbT8j

Comment: @WoJ I was wrong, This example from [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YV3W23ZbT8j) is more representative.  The second `resp` pointer assignment mimic your second http.Get(...).  I think each `defer` keep a copy of each pointer respecteively.

Comment: @mgagnon Got it. I have updated the answer. Thank!